# How to know a operations of Google AppEngine datastore are complete

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I'm execute method Datastore.delete(key) form my GWT web application, AsyncCallback had call onSuccess() method    .Them i refresh `http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin` immediately , the Entity i intent to delete still exist. Smilar to, I refresh my GWT web application immediately the item i intent to delete still show on web page.Note the the onSuccess() had been call.

So, how can i know when the Entity already deleted ?

```
 public void deleteALocation(int removedIndex,String symbol ){
    if(Window.confirm("Sure ?")){
        System.out.println("XXXXXX  " +symbol);
        loCalservice.deletoALocation(symbol, callback_delete_location);
    }

}
public AsyncCallback<String> callback_delete_location = new AsyncCallback<String>() {      

    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        Window.alert(caught.getMessage());
    }

    public void onSuccess(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int removedIndex = ArryList_Location.indexOf(result);
        ArryList_Location.remove(removedIndex);
        LocationTable.removeRow(removedIndex + 1);
        //Window.alert(result+"!!!");
    }
};
```

SERver :

```
public String deletoALocation(String name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Transaction tx = Datastore.beginTransaction();
    Key key = Datastore.createKey(Location.class,name);
    Datastore.delete(tx,key); 
    tx.commit();
    return name;
}
```

Sorry i'm not good at english :-)

Comment: Do a query to the database to obtain the actual data each time you reload your page.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions#put)

> Returns the Key object (if one model instance is given) or a list of Key objects (if a list of instances is given) that correspond with the stored model instances.

If you need an example of a working delete function, this might [help](https://github.com/buslinks/myblog/blob/master/views.py).   Line 108

```
class DeletePost(BaseHandler):

def get(self, post_id):
    iden = int(post_id)
    post = db.get(db.Key.from_path('Posts', iden))
    db.delete(post)
    return webapp2.redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you check the existence of the entity? Via a query?

Queries on HRD are [eventually consistent](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency), meaning that if you add/delete/change an entity then immediately query for it you might not see the changes. The reason for this is that when you write (or delete) an entity, GAE asynchronously updates the index and entity [in several phases](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/life_of_write). Since this takes some time it might happen that you don't see the changes immediately.

Linked article discusses ways to mitigate this limitation.